# SharePoint 2013 event receiver error

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, remote-event-receiver, office-365-developer

I am currently working on a SharePoint online project. My code generates 6 documents in 6 different document libraries along with other metadata. When I save data to a List, the event receiver fires and creates all the 6 documents. But sometimes it stops creating the 6 documents and left with 1 or 2 documents. Sometimes documents has been created but without any metadata.

The same code is working fine in my on-premises environment, but it sometimes breaks in the Office 365 environment. I also created a log list to track the issue as we cannot debug in Office 365. In the log list I found a error message saying "Thread was being aborted." Below is my code. please help it is happening only in Office 365 environment.

```
namespace ExcelGen.ExcelGenReceiver
{
using System;

using Microsoft.SharePoint;

/// <summary>
/// List Item Events
/// </summary>
public class ExcelGenReceiver : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The template URL
    /// </summary>
    private const string TemplateUrl = "/Quotation Analysis Electrical/Forms/Quotation Analysis Sheet ELEC_Blank.xlsm";

    /// <summary>
    /// The template url1
    /// </summary>
    private const string TemplateUrl1 = "/Quotation Analysis Mechanical/Forms/Quotation Analysis Sheet MECH_Blank.xlsm";

    /// <summary>
    /// The template url2
    /// </summary>
    private const string TemplateUrl2 = "/TenderSummaryLib/Forms/TenderSummaryBlankMaster1.xlsm";

    /// <summary>
    /// The RFI template URL
    /// </summary>
    private const string RfiTemplateUrl = "/EstimatingRFI/Forms/RFI Schedule MASTER.docx";

    /// <summary>
    /// The drawing template URL
    /// </summary>
    private const string DrawingTemplateUrl = "/Tender and Drawing Schedule/Forms/Tender Document Drawing Schedule.docx";

    /// <summary>
    /// The tender return template URL
    /// </summary>
    private const string TenderReturnTemplateUrl = "/Est_Tender_Pricing_Document/Forms/Tender Pricing Document blank.xlsm";

    /// <summary>
    /// The project number
    /// </summary>
    private string projectNumber = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// The project name
    /// </summary>
    private string projectName = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// The no bid
    /// </summary>
    private string noBid;

    /// <summary>
    /// The team
    /// </summary>
    private string team;

    /// <summary>
    /// The description
    /// </summary>
    private string description;

    /// <summary>
    /// The status
    /// </summary>
    private string status;

    /// <summary>
    /// The electrical
    /// </summary>
    private SPUser electrical;

    /// <summary>
    /// The mechanical
    /// </summary>
    private SPUser mechanical;

    /// <summary>
    /// The document date
    /// </summary>
    private DateTime? docDate;

    /// <summary>
    /// The tender received
    /// </summary>
    private DateTime? tenderReceived;

    /// <summary>
    /// The tender return
    /// </summary>
    private DateTime? tenderReturn;

    /// <summary>
    /// The pre construction program start date
    /// </summary>
    private DateTime? preConstructionProgramStart;

    /// <summary>
    /// The pre construction program end date
    /// </summary>
    private DateTime? preConstructionProgramEnd;

    /// <summary>
    /// The sector
    /// </summary>
    private string sector;

    /// <summary>
    /// The design build
    /// </summary>
    private string designBuild;

    /// <summary>
    /// The build type
    /// </summary>
    private string buildType;

    /// <summary>
    /// The service program start date
    /// </summary>
    private DateTime? serviceProgramStart;

    /// <summary>
    /// The service program completion date
    /// </summary>
    private DateTime? serviceProgramCompletion;

    /// <summary>
    /// The client1
    /// </summary>
    private string client1;

    /// <summary>
    /// The client2
    /// </summary>
    private string client2;

    /// <summary>
    /// The client3
    /// </summary>
    private string client3;

    /// <summary>
    /// The client4
    /// </summary>
    private string client4;

    /// <summary>
    /// The consultant
    /// </summary>
    private string consultant;

    /// <summary>
    /// An item is being added.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="properties">The Item Event properties</param>
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        //this.EventFiringEnabled = false;

        var web = properties.Web;
        var listItem = properties.ListItem;

        try
        {
            LogIssue(web, null, "Item Added", "List Item Id {0}", listItem.ID);

            if (!this.AttemptCopyProcess(listItem))
            {
                LogIssue(web, null, "List Id : " + listItem.ID, "AttemptCopyProcess failed.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogIssue(web, ex, "List Id : " + listItem.ID, "AttemptCopyProcess failed.");
        }
        finally
        {
            //this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
            LogIssue(web, null, "List Id : " + listItem.ID, "Event Receiver completed sucessfully.");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Logs any issues found
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="webContext">The web context.</param>
    /// <param name="exception">The exception, if null not exception details are written</param>
    /// <param name="contextId">The context identifier, a unique identifier that allows us to know where the call originated, i.e. a List and ListItem Id, or a Page Url</param>
    /// <param name="comment">The comment.</param>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments.</param>
    private static void LogIssue(SPWeb webContext, Exception exception, string contextId, string comment, params object[] args)
    {
        //// if (webContext.AllProperties.ContainsKey("EnableLogging"))
        //// {
            var list = webContext.Lists.TryGetList("ErrorIssues");
            if (list != null)
            {
                var item = list.AddItem();

                item["Title"] = contextId;

                if (exception != null)
                {
                    item["Message"] = exception.Message;
                    item["InnerException"] = exception.InnerException ?? (object)string.Empty;
                    item["StackTrace"] = exception.StackTrace;
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comment))
                {
                    item["Comment"] = string.Format(comment, args);
                }

                item.Update();
            }
        //// }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Assigns the field.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listItem">The list item.</param>
    /// <param name="fieldName">Name of the field.</param>
    /// <param name="contextId">The context identifier.</param>
    /// <returns>The fields string value if present, otherwise string.empty.</returns>
    private static string AssignField(SPListItem listItem, string fieldName, string contextId)
    {
        var fieldValue = string.Empty;

        if (listItem.Fields.ContainsField(fieldName) && listItem[fieldName] != null)
        {
            fieldValue = listItem[fieldName].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            LogIssue(listItem.Web, null, contextId, string.Format("Field not available : {0}", fieldName));
        }

        return fieldValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Assigns the field as a DateTime
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listItem">The list item.</param>
    /// <param name="fieldName">Name of the field.</param>
    /// <param name="contextId">The context identifier.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the date if found, otherwise returns DateTime.MinValue</returns>
    private static DateTime? AssignDateField(SPListItem listItem, string fieldName, string contextId)
    {
        DateTime? fieldValue = null;

        if (listItem.Fields.ContainsField(fieldName) && listItem[fieldName] != null)
        {
            fieldValue = Convert.ToDateTime(listItem[fieldName].ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            LogIssue(listItem.Web, null, contextId, string.Format("Field not available : {0}", fieldName));
        }

        return fieldValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the folder.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listdoc">The list.</param>
    /// <param name="folderName">Name of the folder.</param>
    private static void CreateFolder(SPList listdoc, string folderName)
    {

        LogIssue(listdoc.ParentWeb, null, "List Id : " + listdoc.ID, "Creating folder {0} in {1}", folderName, listdoc.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);

        // Updated by Indusnet
        SPListItem folder1 = listdoc.Items.Add(listdoc.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder);
        folder1["Name"] = folderName;
        folder1.Update();
        listdoc.Update();
        // End Updated
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Assigns the user field.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listItem">The list item.</param>
    /// <param name="fieldName">Name of the field.</param>
    /// <param name="contextId">The context identifier.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the user if found, otherwise null.</returns>
    private static SPUser AssignUserField(SPListItem listItem, string fieldName, string contextId)
    {
        SPUser user = null;

        if (listItem.Fields.ContainsField(fieldName) && listItem[fieldName] != null)
        {
            var userField = (SPFieldUser)listItem.Fields.GetField(fieldName);
            var fieldValue = (SPFieldUserValue)userField.GetFieldValue(listItem["electrical_proj_manager"].ToString());

            user = fieldValue.User;
        }
        else
        {
            LogIssue(listItem.Web, null, contextId, string.Format("Field not available : {0}", fieldName));
        }

        return user;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts the copy process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listItem">The list item.</param>
    /// <returns>True if it successfully processed, false otherwise.</returns>
    private bool AttemptCopyProcess(SPListItem listItem)
    {
        if (listItem.ParentList.Title != "Enquiry_Template")
        {
            LogIssue(listItem.Web, null, "List Id : " + listItem.ID, "ListItem titles is not Enquiry_Template, aborting.");
            return false;
        }

        var finalNum = "15-" + new Random().Next(0, 9999).ToString("D4");

        this.Initialize(listItem, finalNum);

        if (this.noBid != "Yes")
        {
            LogIssue(listItem.Web, null, "List Id : " + listItem.ID, "The noBid field does not equal Yes, aborting.");
            return false;
        }

        this.CopyFiles(listItem.Web, finalNum);
        this.CreateFolders(listItem.Web);



        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Copies the files.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="web">The web.</param>
    /// <param name="finalNum">The final number.</param>
    private void CopyFiles(SPWeb web, string finalNum)
    {
        LogIssue(web, null, "Web Id : " + web.ID, "Setting the copying of files ...");

        var mechanicalQuoteList = web.Lists["Quotation Analysis Mechanical"];
        var electricalQuoteList = web.Lists["Quotation Analysis Electrical"];
        var tenderSummarList = web.Lists["TenderSummaryLib"];
        var estimatingList = web.Lists["EstimatingRFI"];
        var tenderSheduleList = web.Lists["Tender and Drawing Schedule"];
        var tenderPricingList = web.Lists["Est_Tender_Pricing_Document"];

        var url1 = mechanicalQuoteList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;
        var url = electricalQuoteList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;
        var url2 = tenderSummarList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;
        var urlA = estimatingList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;
        var urlB = tenderSheduleList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;
        var urlC = tenderPricingList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;

        var foldername1 = string.Empty;
        var foldername = string.Empty;
        var foldername2 = string.Empty;
        var foldernameA = string.Empty;
        var foldernameB = string.Empty;
        var foldernameC = string.Empty;

        var folder1 = web.Folders[url1 + "/" + foldername1];
        var folder = web.Folders[url + "/" + foldername];
        var folder2 = web.Folders[url2 + "/" + foldername2];
        var folderA = web.Folders[urlA + "/" + foldernameA];
        var folderB = web.Folders[urlB + "/" + foldernameB];
        var folderC = web.Folders[urlC + "/" + foldernameC];

        if (!folder1.Exists && !folder.Exists && !folder2.Exists && !folderA.Exists && !folderB.Exists && !folderC.Exists)
        {
            var folders1 = web.GetFolder(url1).SubFolders;
            var folders = web.GetFolder(url).SubFolders;
            var folders2 = web.GetFolder(url2).SubFolders;
            var foldersA = web.GetFolder(urlA).SubFolders;
            var foldersB = web.GetFolder(urlB).SubFolders;
            var foldersC = web.GetFolder(urlC).SubFolders;
            folders1.Add(foldername1);
            folders.Add(foldername);
            folders2.Add(foldername2);
            foldersA.Add(foldernameA);
            foldersB.Add(foldernameB);
            foldersC.Add(foldernameC);
        }

        var file1 = web.GetFile(web.Site.Url + TemplateUrl1);
        var file = web.GetFile(web.Site.Url + TemplateUrl);
        var file2 = web.GetFile(web.Site.Url + TemplateUrl2);
        var fileA = web.GetFile(web.Site.Url + RfiTemplateUrl);
        var fileB = web.GetFile(web.Site.Url + DrawingTemplateUrl);
        var fileC = web.GetFile(web.Site.Url + TenderReturnTemplateUrl);

        if (file1 != null && file != null && file2 != null && fileA != null && fileB != null && fileC != null)
        {

            var fileName = string.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", folder1.ServerRelativeUrl, this.projectName, ".xlsm");
            LogIssue(web, null, "Web Id : " + web.ID, "Copying file 1 {0} to {1}...", file1.Name, fileName);

            var byteArray1 = file1.OpenBinary();
            var uploadedFile1 = folder1.Files.Add(fileName, byteArray1, true);
            LogIssue(web, null, "Web Id : " + web.ID, "File 1 Uploaded with new ID of {0}", uploadedFile1.Item.ID);

            this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
            var listitem1 = uploadedFile1.Item;
            listitem1["Name"] = this.projectName;
            listitem1["EnquiryNo"] = finalNum;
            listitem1["Project_Name"] = this.projectName;
            listitem1["Tender_Received"] = this.tenderReceived;
            listitem1["Tender_Return"] = this.tenderReturn;

            listitem1["Quotation_Analysis_Mech_Url"] = "https://my site url/Quotation%20Analysis%20Mechanical/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + listitem1.ID;
            listitem1.SystemUpdate(false);
            this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
            LogIssue(web, null, "Web Id : " + web.ID, "Copied file 1.");




            fileName = string.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", folder.ServerRelativeUrl, this.projectName, ".xlsm");
            LogIssue(web, null, "Web Id : " + web.ID, "Copying file 2 {0} to {1}...", file.Name, fileName);

            var byteArray = file.OpenBinary();
            var uploadedFile = folder.Files.Add(fileName, byteArray, true);
            LogIssue(web, null, "Web Id : " + web.ID, "File 2 Uploaded with new ID of {0}", uploadedFile.Item.ID);

            this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
            var listitem = uploadedFile.Item;
            listitem["Name"] = this.projectName;
            listitem["EnquiryNo"] = finalNum;
            listitem["Project_Name"] = this.projectName;
            listitem["Tender_Received"] = this.tenderReceived;
            listitem["Tender_Return"] = this.tenderReturn;

            listitem["Quotation_Analysis_Elec_Url"] = "https://my site url/Quotation%20Analysis%20Electrical/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + listitem.ID;
            listitem.SystemUpdate(false);
            this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
            LogIssue(web, null, "Web Id : " + web.ID, "Copied file 2.");



            fileName = string.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", folderA.ServerRelativeUrl, this.projectName, ".docx");
            LogIssue(web, null, "Web Id : " + web.ID, "Copying file 3 {0} to {1}...", fileA.Name, fileName);

            var byteArrayA = fileA.OpenBinary();
            var uploadedFileA = folderA.Files.Add(fileName, byteArrayA, true);
            LogIssue(web, null, "Web Id : " + web.ID, "File 3 Uploaded with new ID of {0}", uploadedFileA.Item.ID);
            this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
            var listitemA = uploadedFileA.Item;
            listitemA["Name"] = this.projectName;
            listitemA["EnquiryNo"] = finalNum;
            listitemA["Project_Name"] = this.projectName;
            listitemA["Date"] = this.docDate;
            listitemA["Description"] = this.description;
            listitemA["ProjectNo"] = this.projectNumber;
            listitemA["RFIUrl"] = "https://my site url/EstimatingRFI/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + listitemA.ID;
            listitemA.SystemUpdate(false);
            this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
            LogIssue(web, null, "Web Id : " + web.ID, "Copied file 3.");



            fileName = string.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", folderB.ServerRelativeUrl, this.projectName, ".docx");
            LogIssue(web, null, "Web Id : " + web.ID, "Copying file 4 {0} to {1}...", fileB.Name, fileName);

            var byteArrayB = fileB.OpenBinary();
            var uploadedFileB = folderB.Files.Add(fileName, byteArrayB, true);
            LogIssue(web, null, "Web Id : " + web.ID, "File 4 Uploaded with new ID of {0}", uploadedFileB.Item.ID);

            this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
            var listitemB = uploadedFileB.Item;
            listitemB["Name"] = this.projectName;
            listitemB["EnquiryNo"] = finalNum;
            listitemB["Project_Name"] = this.projectName;
            listitemB["Date"] = this.docDate;
            listitemB["Description"] = this.description;
            listitemB["ProjectNo"] = this.projectNumber;
            listitemB["DrawingURL"] = "https://my site url/Tender%20and%20Drawing%20Schedule/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + listitemB.ID;
            listitemB.SystemUpdate(false);
            this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
            LogIssue(web, null, "Web Id : " + web.ID, "Copied file 4.");


            fileName = string.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", folderC.ServerRelativeUrl, this.projectName, ".xlsm");
            LogIssue(web, null, "Web Id : " + web.ID, "Copying file 5 {0} to {1}...", fileC.Name, fileName);

            var byteArrayC = fileC.OpenBinary();
            var uploadedFileC = folderC.Files.Add(fileName, byteArrayC, true);

            LogIssue(web, null, "Web Id : " + web.ID, "File 5 Uploaded with new ID of {0}", uploadedFileC.Item.ID);
            this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
            var listitemC = uploadedFileC.Item;
            listitemC["Name"] = this.projectName;
            listitemC["EnquiryNo"] = finalNum;
            listitemC["Project_Name"] = this.projectName;
            listitemC["Date"] = this.docDate;
            listitemC["Description"] = this.description;
            listitemC["ProjectNo"] = this.projectNumber;
            listitemC["PricingURL"] = "https://my site url/Est_Tender_Pricing_Document/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + listitemC.ID;
            listitemC.SystemUpdate(false);
            this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
            LogIssue(web, null, "Web Id : " + web.ID, "Copied file 5.");



            fileName = string.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", folder2.ServerRelativeUrl, this.projectName, ".xlsm");
            LogIssue(web, null, "Web Id : " + web.ID, "Copying file 5 {0} to {1}...", file2.Name, fileName);

            var byteArray2 = file2.OpenBinary();
            var uploadedFile2 = folder2.Files.Add(fileName, byteArray2, true);

            LogIssue(web, null, "Web Id : " + web.ID, "File 6 Uploaded with new ID of {0}", uploadedFile2.Item.ID);
            this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
            var listitem2 = uploadedFile2.Item;
            listitem2["Name"] = this.projectName;
            listitem2["EnquiryNo"] = finalNum;
            listitem2["Project_Name"] = this.projectName;
            listitem2["Date"] = this.docDate;
            listitem2["Team"] = this.team;
            listitem2["Estimator_Electrical"] = this.electrical;
            listitem2["Estimator_Mechanical"] = this.mechanical;
            listitem2["Status"] = this.status;
            listitem2["Tender_Received"] = this.tenderReceived;
            listitem2["Tender_Return"] = this.tenderReturn;
            listitem2["Sector"] = this.sector;
            listitem2["Design_Build"] = this.designBuild;
            listitem2["Build_Type"] = this.buildType;
            listitem2["Service_Prog_Start"] = this.serviceProgramStart;
            listitem2["Service_Prog_Completion"] = this.serviceProgramCompletion;
            listitem2["Client_1"] = this.client1;
            listitem2["Client_2"] = this.client2;
            listitem2["Client_3"] = this.client3;
            listitem2["Client_4"] = this.client4;
            listitem2["Consultant"] = this.consultant;
            listitem2["Pre-construction_Prog_Start"] = this.preConstructionProgramStart;
            listitem2["Pre-construction_Prog_End"] = this.preConstructionProgramEnd;
            listitem2["Tender_Summary_Url"] = "https://my site url/TenderSummaryLib/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + listitem2.ID;
            listitem2.SystemUpdate(false);
            this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
            LogIssue(web, null, "Web Id : " + web.ID, "Copied file 6.");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the folders.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="web">The web.</param>
    private void CreateFolders(SPWeb web)
    {
        var projectListId = web.Lists.Add(this.projectName.Replace(' ', '_'), string.Empty, SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);
        var projectList = web.Lists[projectListId];
        projectList.OnQuickLaunch = true; // The document library will appear in Quick Launch bar.

        CreateFolder(projectList, "1.Tender Documents");
        CreateFolder(projectList, "2. Electrical");
        CreateFolder(projectList, "3. Mechanical");
        CreateFolder(projectList, "4. Correspondance");
        CreateFolder(projectList, "5. Settlement Meeting Docs");
        CreateFolder(projectList, "6. Tender Return Docs");
        CreateFolder(projectList, "7. Tender Handover");

        projectList.Update();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the specified list item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listItem">The list item.</param>
    /// <param name="finalNum">The final number.</param>
    private void Initialize(SPListItem listItem, string finalNum)
    {
        var contextId = string.Format("List:{0}, Id:{1}", listItem.ParentList.Title, listItem.ID);

        this.noBid = AssignField(listItem, "Bid", contextId);
        this.projectName = AssignField(listItem, "Project_Name", contextId);

        var teamlookup = AssignField(listItem, "Team", contextId);
        var lookupParts = teamlookup.Split(new[] { ";#" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        this.team = lookupParts[1];

        this.description = AssignField(listItem, "Description", contextId);
        this.status = AssignField(listItem, "enquiry_status", contextId);

        this.electrical = AssignUserField(listItem, "electrical_proj_manager", contextId);
        this.mechanical = AssignUserField(listItem, "mechanical_proj_manager", contextId);

        this.docDate = AssignDateField(listItem, "Date", contextId);
        this.tenderReceived = AssignDateField(listItem, "Tender_Received", contextId);
        this.tenderReturn = AssignDateField(listItem, "Tender_Return", contextId);
        this.preConstructionProgramStart = AssignDateField(listItem, "Pre-construction_Prog_Start", contextId);
        this.preConstructionProgramEnd = AssignDateField(listItem, "Pre-construction_Prog_End", contextId);

        this.sector = AssignField(listItem, "Sector", contextId);
        this.designBuild = AssignField(listItem, "Design_Build", contextId);
        this.buildType = AssignField(listItem, "Build_Type", contextId);

        this.serviceProgramStart = AssignDateField(listItem, "Service_Prog_Start", contextId);
        this.serviceProgramCompletion = AssignDateField(listItem, "Service_Prog_Completion", contextId);

        this.client1 = AssignField(listItem, "Client_1", contextId);
        this.client2 = AssignField(listItem, "Client_2", contextId);
        this.client3 = AssignField(listItem, "Client_3", contextId);
        this.client4 = AssignField(listItem, "Client_4", contextId);
        this.consultant = AssignField(listItem, "Consultant", contextId);

        if (this.status == "Won")
        {
            this.projectNumber = string.Format("15-{0}-{1}", this.team, new Random().Next(0, 9999).ToString("D4"));
        }

        if (this.status == "Active" || this.status == "Closed")
        {
            this.projectNumber = "No Project No";
        }

        listItem["ProjectNo"] = this.projectNumber;
        listItem["EnquiryNo"] = finalNum;

        listItem.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        listItem.SystemUpdate(false);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am digging out event receiver for SharePoint online for few weeks. I believe SP online supports only Remote Event Receivers. But your code looks like Server side event receiver.

Please confirm how you are doing it.

Thanks,
V.Vetrivelmurugan